# Jackson: exclude field from one JsonView class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a model.

```
public class Model {
    @JsonProperty("model_id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonView(face.Test.class)
    @JsonProperty("model_name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("model_level")
    private Byte level;
    @JsonView(face.New.class)
    @JsonProperty("model_score")
    private Byte score;
    @JsonView(face.Test.Tester.class)
    @JsonProperty("model_community")
    private Long community;

    //getter and setters
}
```

as you can see my `id` and `level` fields will be included in all JSONs which be created from this model.

now I want to put for example field level in all JSONs (which be created from this model) except one.

is there something like `@JsonView(!face.Example.class)` ? if it's not, what is the best solution for this case?

thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use view class inheritance to accomplish this.

```
public class face {
  public static class BaseView {}
  public static class Test extends BaseView {}
  public static class New extends BaseView {}
  public static class Example {} // no parent
}
```

And so:

```
public class Model {

  // included in all views
  private Integer id;

  // only in Test view
  @JsonView(face.Test.class)
  private String name;

  // included in BaseView and its children (ie not Example)
  @JsonView(face.BaseView.class)
  private Byte level;

  // ...
```

}

Presumably you have a logical hierarchy of views that apply to more than just the one field.